# Django admin auto field with prefix

Tags: django, admin, prefix, autofield

I have a auto field that creates a ticket number. however just the number alone looks very un professional. how would I add  "#0000" in front of the auto field and every time the number goes above 1 or two digits the "0" needs to be filled . Hope this makes sense .

```
 Ticket_Number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
  

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.Ticket_Number = '#0000' + self.Ticket_Number
    return super(SupportTicket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def save(self):
    if not self.Ticket_Number:
        lenn = len(SupportTicket.objects.all()) + 1
        prefix = "#000000"
        self.Ticket_Number = prefix[:-len(str(lenn))] + str(lenn)
    super(SupportTicket, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the model's `save` method to achieve this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.Ticket_Number = '#0000' + self.Ticket_Number
    return super(TicketModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Not tested, sorry! You'd probably have some conversion additions...

Comment: i have added the code above to the model but it gives me the can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str, do you think it is because it is an auto field